# UDP fragmentation packet order

Tags: networking, udp, rhel7, rhel6

I send mixtures of large UDP packets back-to-back with small UDP packets.  The large packets get fragmented to my MTU.

- On RHEL6 (CentOS6), the small UDP packets always arrive at the receivers in the correct order with respect to the final fragment of any previous large packet.
- On RHEL7, this no longer is the case.  The small packet can get transmitted in-between the fragments of the larger packet, thus causing the receiver to see the small packet BEFORE the reassembled large packet.

As near as I can tell with ethtool, the configuration of the NIC is the same on both machines (It's actually the same machine and I swap hard drives).

So, my question is... What controls this behavior in RHEL7+?  It's not udp-fragmentation-offload (That's set the same in both configurations).  I'd like to find out how to force the fragments to be transmitted as a complete group, with no interfering packets, in RHEL7+.

Thanks,

XL600

Comment: What's the output of `sudo ethtool -l [INTERFACE_NAME]`? What if you try `sudo ethtool -L [INTERFACE_NAME] combined 1`? Does it help?

Comment: Looks like there’s 4 queues.  Setting it to 1 so far seems to prevent the issue (yeah!).  I’ve been concentrating on UFO and GSO but disabling both (all offloads actually) had no effect on the issue and didn’t even prevent fragmentation (not that I would want that in the first place).  This leads to a new line of investigation.  What in rhel7 has changed so much queuing wise with respect to UDP fragmentation (we’re using igb)?  My rhel6 combined has always been 4.

Comment: As far as I know, kernel version in RHEL 6 is 2.6, whilst in RHEL 7 it's 3.10. It's got to be a huge difference already. Also, it's very likely that the NIC driver has been updated to support new features which might come into play here. The kernel might dispatch processing of oversize packets and the smaller ones to different threads and, thus, to different NIC Tx queues associated with the threads. The queues work in parallel, so it's no surprise reordering may happen at the HW level.

Comment: So, if you were looking to just force the fragments to be sent separately from non-fragment packets, you've got a solution. Should you find it satisfactory, I can post this as an answer. That said, this solution means that multi-queue is no longer used on receive (no RSS), unless your NIC supports decoupling Tx and Rx queue counts. If it's critical to preserve multi-queue optimisations on receive, then perhaps the problem is worth further investigation. In this case, it pays to find out the NIC vendor / model and provide printouts from ethtool that you've managed to collect so far.

Comment: It is a big jump in kernel versions and I suspect you're right about the kernel dispatching the oversize packets to different threads which wind up on separate CPUs.  I would have thought 2.6 would have done this as well, but we haven't seen the issue in 2.6 at all.

Comment: I'd say that your direction leads me in the right direction and can be considered the answer to my immediate question.  Hopefully I'll stumble across more knowledge as I dig deeper.  Thank you for the insights!

Answer (score 0):

If you just would like to force the fragmented UDP packets to be sequential in order without packets in-between, you could enforce this behaviour by:

```
sudo ethtool -L [INTERFACE_NAME] combined 1
```

But in general, it is not good to rely on this. Better to have reader code that does not make this assumption.